Sent to a list of emails based on a subscriber
I have a customer record with mock data as a subscriber. I need to send an email based on this mock user's data to 200+ emails. What is the most straight forward way of going about this? I tried using Preview and Test but I can't just copy/paste 200+ emails. Using the test data extension doesn't work because none of these have a subscriber key. The purpose is to integrate Everest/Validity seed list.

Why not just populate a data extension with same values for all rows, except email address and subscriber key? This is easily doable in SQL/Automation studio?
Assuming you have your 200 recipients in "whatever" data extension:
SELECT emailAddress, 
subscriberKey, 
'John' as firstName, 
'Doe' as lastName,
'1234' as postCode
from Whatever

This will populate your sendable data extension, without the need for having anything but the first two fields populated in 'whatever'

Thank you. That's a great idea for the mock-data. I don't have a unique subscriber key from Validity/Everest, just emails and that email list changes regularly enough. I thought about using the same subscriber key for everyone but someone of those emails hard bounce unfortunately. Unsure what to do about the SubscriberKey since none of these are actual subscribers.
